# request.xhr? triggers true when server is launched from VSCode and ITerm but not when launched on Terminal or Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, devise, routes, xmlhttprequest

**PROBLEM**

I'm storing User's locations to redirect them after sign up/ sign in. I only store locations if request.xhr? is FALSE.

However, request.xhr? is triggering FALSE when launching the rails server form some terminals and TRUE when launching the rails server from some other terminals.

This happens on the same requests for the same code on the same machine. Why does this happen?

**I'VE TRIED**

I've tried testing the same requests on the same machine, the same requests from different machines, and have compared several different requests.

Repeatedly it seems that:

When the rails server is launched from Terminal or AWS Elastic Beanstalk, `request.xhr? == false` which is what I expect.

When the rails server is launched from iTerm or VSCode, `request.xhr? == true` which is not what I expect.

**RELEVANT CODE**

I'm checking for XHR and storing request locations in app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  ...
  before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?
  ...

  private

  def storable_location?
    puts request.fullpath
    puts "CHECKING XHR"
    puts request.xhr? # this is the line that gives differing outputs
    request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr? && !is_a?(::CertificationsController)&& !is_a?(::MainController)
  end

  def store_user_location!
      # :user is the scope we are authenticating
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
  end
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

Expected: false
Actual: true

But only on iTerm or VSCode

(Or I at least expect outputs to not differ based on the terminal I'm using).

Comment: I'm not too sure how VSCode & the like handle requests to/from the server but it may be possible that they are doing some weirdness and passing the requests to the server with xhr headers set to true? (Complete guess)

Comment: @ThorTL67 That sounds plausible! Will look into that more, thank you!